# Display 3 lists (java.util.List)

Tags: groovy

I ask for help to display 3 lists with groovy. In fact I have 3 lists (java.util.list) : the first are 4 checkboxes, the second and third are editable grids with 1 column and 4 fields. All are saved in 3 differents variables java.util.list.

I try to display this 3 lists in a text field area with this loop :

```
def out = []
for (i=0; i<grids1.size();i++) {
    out.add([grids1.getAt(i),checkboxes.getAt(i),grids2.getAt(i)])
}
out
```

but the result is pretty bad.

```
    [[[], checkboxes, []], [[2], checkboxes, [grids2]], [[], null, []],
 [[3], null, [grids2]], [[], null, []]]
```

Could somebody help me ?

#### More info from answer below:

Thanks. We are not so much in a dark because it's almost that!
I have a gap between each data. An example :

3 lists with 4 fields each.

```
def a = [ [], [2], [], [4] ]
def b = [ '', 'two', '', 'four' ]
def c = [ [], [6], [], [8] ]
```

It display like that, with a lag (maybe because the lists **a** and **c** keep the index counter to the **b** list.

```
[[], two, []]
[[2], four, [6]]
[[], , [], []]
[[4], , [], [8]]
```

The list a and b keep their "positions" as opposed to the list b.

Comment: Can you re-word the question so it makes sense?  Is this a GUI app?  You say you have 3 lists, then only show code with 2 of them.  I don't know what you have, or what you want as it stands.

Comment: yes, sorry. It's à GUI app : Bonita, à BPM soft.
In the loop there are 3 lists : grids1, grids2 and checkboxes.
I just want to display this 3 lists like I try in this loop....

Comment: Still not sure, but do you mean like: `String out = [grids1,checkboxes,grids2].transpose().join( '\n' )` (do you want it somehow as a String? I guess so as you mention a text field)  What output are you expecting?

Comment: thank you, it's better now. 
But how can I remove empty values with index ? I tried with removeAll("") and replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));  but it doesn't work...

Comment: What do you want in place of the empty lists `[]`?

Comment: nothing if it's possible. I want delete all the empty entries in each list.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your input data is, or what output you desire (maybe add some example inputs and required outputs to your question?), this is a complete shot in the dark...

You can do this sort of thing:

```
def a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [], [ 3, 4 ] ]
def b = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
def c = [ [], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ] ]

String s = [a,b,c].transpose()              // Join the lists
                  .collect { it.findAll() } // Remove empty entries
                  .join( '\n' )             // Join into a string with newlines
println s
```

Which prints:

```
[[1, 2], one]
[two, [5, 6]]
[[3, 4], three, [7, 8]]
```

But as I say, it's hard to really know if this is even going in the right direction...

#### Edit after update:

This:

```
def a = [ [], [2], [], [4] ]
def b = [ '', 'two', '', 'four' ]
def c = [ [], [6], [], [8] ]

String s = [ a, b, c ].transpose().join( '\n' )

println s
```

Prints:

```
[[], , []]
[[2], two, [6]]
[[], , []]
[[4], four, [8]]
```

Is that closer?

Comment: It's the same problem... I don't understand why. The result is like this : 
`[[], two, []]
[[2], four, [6]]
[[], , []]
[[4], , [8]]`